# Can't Execute Makefile, Even As Root!

Tags: make, permission-denied

I'm trying to compile a `c` program, but when I try to execute the `makefile`, I get "Permission denied".

This is what I did :

```
root@mycpu:/usr/bin# MakeFile
-bash: /usr/bin/MakeFile: Permission denied
root@mycpu:/usr/bin#
```

Comment: Makefiles are usually executed explicitly with `make` e.g. `make -f MakeFile` or just `make` if you have named the file suitably (it will look for a `makefile` or `Makefile` in the current directory by default).

Comment: Why do you have a Makefile in ``/usr/bin``. Normally that’s not the location for building programs.

Comment: This question looks like one of those nightmares which don't make any sense but are scary as hell.

Comment: I don't get why this question is downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off:

1. Don't compile things as `root`, it is totally unnecessary. It may be needed for the final `make install`, but most likely not otherwise.
2. Don't compile things in `/usr/bin`, that's where (base system) utilities are installed.

Instead:

1. Compile things as "you" (ordinary user).
2. Compile things somewhere in your home directory, for example in a temporary `~/build` directory under which you have unpacked the sources.

The Makefile is not an executable. It is a file containing instructions for the `make` program for how to build a particular piece of software.

You use the Makefile by simply typing `make`.

If the software came with any installation instructions (look for an `INSTALL` file), read them.

Comment: Man, I feel stupid. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @GremlinsBane The stupider you feel, the less likely it is that you will be in the same situation again. Also, I have definitely done things like this!  :-)

Comment: That's encouraging!

Comment: A common Debian trick is for a `debian/rules` file to be an executable makefile, with `#!/usr/bin/make -sf` as its interpreter.  But at beginner level, yes, makefiles are not directly executable.